# WinError 206 while installing Jupyterlab

Tags: command-line, pip, jupyter-lab

I want to install jupyterlab in my Windows 10 laptop but when I run the command `pip install jupyterlab` I am getting the following error:[image]

I tried to look for answers but didn't get any. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem and it turns out the reason behind this error is that Jupyterlab isn't compatible with Python versions 3.8 and above. You can try to uninstall your current version of python and reinstall python 3.7 and then install Jupyterlab again.